# Overlay canvas over canvas

Tags: css, html, canvas

I have following code below, using a JavaScript library, I can draw in first canvas then merge to the second canvas.

The question is, how do I make the first canvas to be static or float, regardless where I scroll the second canvas.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
}
#canvas1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
#canvas2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas2" height="1200" width="800"></canvas>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wz2g8hwz/

Comment: Add an additional container element around the second canvas, and enable scrolling only in that container ...

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you show me in the snippet? Thanks.

Comment: Right now you are scrolling the element that contains _both_ of your canvas - so both of them move. So, put the second canvas into its own container element, and set overflow for that instead, so that only the content of that container (which is only the second canvas) moves ...

Comment: Sorry I totally have no clue, I tried this, https://jsfiddle.net/wz2g8hwz/1/, and this, https://jsfiddle.net/wz2g8hwz/2/, but nothing close to what I want.

Comment: The new container element needs to be positioned the same way as the second canvas was before (absolute), and that canvas itself then _not_ absolute any more ... simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/wz2g8hwz/3/ (canvas replaced by images, so that you can actually see the effect)

Comment: Awesome bro! post your answer below, i'll mark it as answered. have a great weekend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are scrolling the element that contains both of your canvas - so both of them move. So, put the second canvas into its own container element, and set overflow for that instead, so that only the content of that container (which is only the second canvas) moves.

The new container element needs to be positioned the same way as the second canvas was before (absolute), and that canvas itself then not absolute any more.

In the following example I replaced the empty canvasses with images, so the effect becomes visible. https://jsfiddle.net/wz2g8hwz/4/

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

#canvas1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#innerContainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#canvas2 {
  opacity: .5;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img id="canvas1" src="https://placehold.co/400x200">
  <div id="innerContainer">
    <img id="canvas2" src="https://placehold.co/1200x800">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add `width:100%` and `height:100%` on #canvas2.

Like this.

```
#canvas2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it is not what I want. Thanks anyway